# Where to define the conduit xml node for Basic Authentication in a client stub generated by Apache CXF?

Tags: java, authentication, https, cxf, stub

I have retrieved a `wdsl` file over Https from a Soap server serving the web-services that I must work with. Then, with Apache Cxf `wsdl2java`, I have created the client stub so as to check the communication with the web-services server.

I know the remote server is password-protected (and secured with https) so, as expected, the remote server returns `HTTP error 401` when I launch the stub. Alright I need to authenticate.

[In the Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) , they first introduce to **Basic Authentication**, which looks like:

```
 <conduit name="{http://example.com/}HelloWorldServicePort.http-conduit"
   xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
   xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration">
   <authorization>
      <sec:UserName>myuser</sec:UserName>
      <sec:Password>mypasswd</sec:Password>
      <sec:AuthorizationType>Basic</sec:AuthorizationType>
   </authorization>
 </conduit>
```

However, the code generated by CXF doesn't contain any configuration xml file.
So I do wonder where I am to put this xml configuration for authentication ?

And I wonder what `{http://example.com/}HelloWorldServicePort.http-conduit` is corresponding to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [configure the conduit programmatically](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-Usingjavacode) if you don't want to use a configuration file. Create an [AuthorizationPolicy](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/configuration/security/AuthorizationPolicy.html), and use [HTTPConduit.setAuthorization](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduit.html#setAuthorization%28org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy%29) to set it on the conduit.  Otherwise, you are going to want to [use Spring](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html) to configure the client.